# About WM_MOUSEHOVER, controls and Balloons

Tags: c++, winapi, events, onmouseover, popup-balloons

I have this code in the switch (msg) loop inside WindowProc on my GUI App.

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:

```
         TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
         tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
         tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER;
         tme.dwHoverTime = 100;
         tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
         TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
    break;
    case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
         DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG), hwnd, AboutDlg);
    break;
```

I was wondering if I could do anything to have event WM_MOUSEOVER only when I hover over a Control of the window (in this case a CHECKBUTTON)

I need this because I want some explanation about this checkbox (I don't want to write it on the label)  to popup when the mouse is over it. I don't want either a DialogBox... is there any Balloon (or something without an OK button) that appears and dissappears instead a dialogbox or messagebox?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a *tooltip*. They often don't require you to track any mouse events at all. You can even make them look like speech balloons. To get started, read about them in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760250.aspx).

Comment: I found that yesterday afternoon but I don't know what I'm doing wrongly, because it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You're going to need to be more specific that "it doesn't work" if you expect to get help, though. Consider asking a new question about how to use tooltips.